# removing all rows if a row = 0 for certain number of days per quarter

Tags: r, dplyr

First and foremost, thank you for taking YOUR time to view/answer my question.

I am getting a bit stuck on this question - I believe I am close but could not get to my desired solution. I have quite a bit of stock data, see example below.

```
id     date     qtr     price   volume  
1     2/8/12   2012 Q1   101        0
1     2/9/12   2012 Q1   101.1     105
1     2/17/12  2012 Q1   102.1      0
1     3/13/12  2012 Q1   104.1      0
1     5/12/12  2012 Q2   99.1       0
1     5/14/12  2012 Q2   101.1     24
2     2/12/12  2012 Q1   4          0
2     2/15/12  2012 Q1   4          0
2     3/19/12  2012 Q1   4.5       102
2     5/12/12  2012 Q2   6.5       291
2     5/13/12  2012 Q2   6.54      45
```

Essentially, I want to group_by(qtr, id), and If the volume is 0 for a security for **more than 3 days** - I want to remove it from the DF for that quarter.

I am assuming the formula would look something like this:

`df %>% group_by(qtr, id) %>% filter(.....)`

I have looked at other similar questions, however, most of them use `rowSums`, but not sure how that can be applicable in this case.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id, qtr) %>% 
  filter(sum(volume == 0) <= 3)
```

Or with data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, if(sum(volume == 0) <= 3) .SD, by = .(id, qtr)]
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `rle` within the `filter` out the 'qtr', 'id' that have 'volume' for consecutively 3 days or more

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(qtr, id) %>% 
  filter(with(rle(volume == 0), !any(lengths[values] >= 3)))
```

NOTE: Using the above example, it would give the full dataset as the condition is not satisfied

Here, we assumed about consecutive 'volume'.  If it is not the case, i.e. any 3 days per each group, one option similar to @RyanD's in `base R` would be

```
df[with(df, ave(volume == 0, id, qtr, FUN = sum) <=3),]
```

Comment: I should've been more specific, it doesn't have to be 3 consecutive days.. just 3 days out of the entire qtr.. regardless, very neat solution akrun!

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>% 
  mutate(volume_ind = volume == 0) %>%
  group_by(qtr, id) %>%
  mutate(volume_ind = sum(volume_ind)))  %>%
  ungroup %>%
  filter(volume_ind <3) %>%
  select(-volume_ind)
```

Comment: Thank you @Mouad_S, very neat